# Tag guidance spotlight - is the hacking tag representative of group consensus?

Tags: discussion, tags

I wanted to hi-light recent changes to the [hacking](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/hacking/info) tag on the main site.

I took out all the “dictionary” definition from the excerpt and made it 100% about usage guidance - what should be tagged and what shouldn’t.

Are these edits keeping with group consensus on what we should expect from this tag?

Once that’s established - we can see about retagging questions if needed if some of the usage for this tag is outside the usage guidelines.

Comment: I have [rejected the tag wiki](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/265258) on the grounds of being [copied content](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/26361/hacking) without attribution.

Comment: Haven't checked what's tagged in this way. But it feels quite unfortunate that this partial and negative aspect of a two-part meaning seems to prevail. Compare the original, positive  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker  Perhaps a synonym of "criminal activities", "system intrusion" or other more direct phrases might be better? For me, "hacking" is much more 'understanding', 'engineering', 'tinkering' 'fun with technology' etc.

Comment: @LangLangC I would support that as well, but without consensus here it’s going to be very hard to change the prevailing usage.